# Library that includes undefined behavior function working on a certain compiler is portable?

Tags: c++, portability

If I compiled a library that includes an undefined behavior function guaranteed to work on a certain compiler,   is it portable to other compilers?

I thought that the library has already generated assembly, so, when other programs call UB function, the function assembly well-defined to a certain compiler would be executed.

What am I getting wrong here?

Comment: The phrases "work on a certain compiler" and "portable to other compilers" contradict each other.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: No, they do not. The question is asking about source code that is guaranteed to work with one compiler and its generated object module working with other compilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not look to the C++ standard for all your answers.

The C++ standard does not define the behavior when object modules compiled by different compilers are linked together. The jurisdiction of the C++ standard is solely single C++ implementations whose creators choose to conform to the C++ standard.

Linking together different object modules is covered by an application binary interface (ABI). If you compile two functions with two compilers that both conform to the same ABI and link them with a linker that conforms to the ABI, they generally should work together. There are additional details to consider, such as how various things in the language(s) bind to corresponding things in the ABI. For example, one compiler might map `long` to some 32-bit integer type in the ABI while the other compiler might map `long` to some 64-bit integer type, and this would of course interfere with the functions working together unless corresponding adjustments were made.

Comment: If I assume that the compilers conform to the same ABI?
The only difference is that The compiler that compiled the library guarantees that the exported function is Not UB, but the other compilers are not.

Comment: @EunhoChoi: “UB” is not a thing. It is not some taint that sticks to software and spreads. It is a shorthand for saying “The C++ standard does not define the behavior.” But the C++ standard is not the only thing around. If your compiler defines the behavior, then it defines the behavior. You then have a definition of the behavior. The software’s behavior is defined and may be relied upon. If the compiler further conforms to an ABI, you can rely on the compiled module to work with other modules using that ABI.

Comment: @Taekahn: The comment is not disingenuous in the least. You might want to review the dictionary meaning of that word. You have not stated what you find fault with in the comment or what you think a correct statement would be. The comment correctly characterizes “undefined behavior”: It is not a thing, merely a lack of a thing (a lack of specification), which can be filled in, and the fact that the C++ standard may describe some code as “undefined behavior” is limited only to the jurisdiction of the standard and is not a reason to avoid that code if something else satisfactorily defines it.

Comment: I agree with @EricPostpischil and the definition of UB - however you need to make sure that the code that contains the UB is wholly within the library and is not exposed (for example in a header file) to another compiler that does not give the same guarantees.